# On a homeomorphism problem of complex projective space.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, projective-space

> Show that $\Bbb C P^n - \Bbb C P^{n-1} \cong \Bbb C^n.$

There is an obvious embedding of $\Bbb C P^{n-1}$ into $\Bbb C P^n$ given by $$[z_0,z_1, \cdots, z_{n-1}] \longmapsto [z_0,z_1, \cdots, z_{n-1}, 0].$$ In view of this embedding we can think of the elements of $\Bbb C P^n - \Bbb C P^{n-1}$ as the elements of $\Bbb C P^n$ of the form $[z_0,z_1, \cdots, z_n],$ where $z_n \neq 0.$ Since $\Bbb C P^n \cong (\Bbb C^{n+1} - 0) / (\Bbb C - 0)$ it follows that if $z_n \neq 0$ then $$[z_0,z_1, \cdots, z_n] = [z_0', z_1', \cdots, z_{n-1}', 1]$$ where $z_i' = \frac {z_i} {z_n},$ for $i = 0,1,2, \cdots, n-1.$ Consider the map $f : \Bbb C^n \longrightarrow \Bbb CP^n - \Bbb C P^{n-1}$ defined by $$(w_0, w_1, \cdots, w_{n-1}) \longmapsto [w_0, w_1, \cdots, w_{n-1}, 1].$$ Then $f = p \circ \iota,$ where $p : \Bbb C^{n+1} - 0 \longrightarrow (\Bbb C^{n+1} - 0)/ (\Bbb C - 0)$ is the quotient map whose image is $\Bbb C P^n - \Bbb C P^{n-1}$ and $\iota : \Bbb C^n \longrightarrow \Bbb C^{n+1} - 0$ is the inclusion given by $$(w_0, w_1, \cdots, w_{n-1}) \longmapsto (w_0, w_1, \cdots, w_{n-1},1).$$ So $f$ is continuous. Now consider the map $g : \Bbb C P^n - \Bbb C P^{n-1} \longrightarrow \Bbb C^n$ defined by $$[z_0,z_1, \cdots, z_n] \longmapsto (z_0', z_1', \cdots, z_{n-1}')$$ where $z_i' = \frac {z_i} {z_n},$ for $i = 0, 1, 2, \cdots, n-1.$ Then it is easy to see that $f$ and $g$ are inverses of each other. So if we can somehow show that $g$ is continuous then we are through. But I am unable to show that. Would anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** $:$ I am able to show that $$\Bbb C P^n - \Bbb C P^{n-1} \cong (\Bbb C^{n+1} - \Bbb C^n)/(\Bbb C - 0),$$ where the elements of $\Bbb C^n - \Bbb C^{n-1}$ are of the form $(z_0,z_1, \cdots, z_n),$ $z_i \in \Bbb C,$ for $i = 0, 1,2, \cdots, n$ and $z_n \neq 0.$ Now by the virtue of universal property of quotient topology, in order to prove the continuity of $g$ it is enough to show that the map $h : \Bbb C^{n+1} - \Bbb C^n \longrightarrow \Bbb C^n$ defined by $$(z_0,z_1, \cdots, z_n) \longmapsto (z_0', z_1', \cdots, z_{n-1}')$$ where $z_i' = \frac {z_i} {z_n},$ for $i = 0,1,2, \cdots, n-1,$ is a surjective continuous map with the fibres being the orbits of $\Bbb C^{n+1} - \Bbb C^n$ under the action of $\Bbb C - 0$ on $\Bbb C^{n+1} - \Bbb C^n$ by left (or right) multiplication which is somewhat an easy verification.

Comment: So what remains open?

Comment: Finally I am able to solve it @Paul Frost. I have a question. Can I ask you sir?

Comment: Then you should transform your edit into an official answer.

Comment: Is it permissible to answer my own question @Paul Frost sir?

Comment: @Paul Frost as per your advice I have transformed the edited part of my attempt to an official answer. Please have a look at it now.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. You should also accept it.

Comment: @Paul Frost Thanks sir for sharing the link for letting me informed about the norms regarding self-answering of one's own question in this site.

Comment: And I warmly recommend to accept the answer. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. In the present state  the question will remain in the uanswered queue which is confusing for the users. If you click at "Unanswered" in the upper left corne of this page, you will read something like "320,238 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers ", the number of course growing. If you look at these questions, you will see that a great many are actually answered - but it is not visible in the queue.

Comment: @Paul Frost sir I promise you that I will accept my own answer as soon as the system permits me to do so. Again thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: And, by the way, I do not think it is necessary to address people in this forum by the formal "Sir".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to show that $$\Bbb C P^n - \Bbb C P^{n-1} \cong (\Bbb C^{n+1} - \Bbb C^n)/(\Bbb C - 0),$$ where the elements of $\Bbb C^{n + 1} - \Bbb C^n$ are of the form $(z_0,z_1, \cdots, z_n),$ $z_i \in \Bbb C,$ for $i = 0, 1,2, \cdots, n$ and $z_n \neq 0.$ Now by the virtue of universal property of quotient topology, in order to prove the continuity of $g$ it is enough to show that the map $h : \Bbb C^{n+1} - \Bbb C^n \longrightarrow \Bbb C^n$ defined by $$(z_0,z_1, \cdots, z_n) \longmapsto (z_0', z_1', \cdots, z_{n-1}')$$ where $z_i' = \frac {z_i} {z_n},$ for $i = 0,1,2, \cdots, n-1,$ is a surjective continuous map with the fibres being the orbits of $\Bbb C^{n+1} - \Bbb C^n$ under the action of $\Bbb C - 0$ on $\Bbb C^{n+1} - \Bbb C^n$ by left (or right) multiplication which is somewhat an easy verification.